# Angular 17: standalone </div> in HTML template of component

Tags: html, angular, angular17

I get the structure of the page rendered from an api so I have multiple components for text fields, dropdowns etc. Now I want to implement an opening div component and a closing div component in order to group same components in same div. So for example from the api I get these 5 entries: DivOpen - Text - Text - Dropdown - DivClose .
So with a switch case I parse the incoming data and translate it to html. The problem is that for DivClose where I want to add  in the html template of DivClose component I get the error `Unexpected closing tag "div". It may happen when the tag has already been closed by another tag.`

How I can create the DivClose element? Here is my switch-case code:

```
@switch (details.objType) {
                    @case ("textbox") {
                        <dynamic-text-input [referringForm]="form" />
                    }
                    @case ("dropdownlist") {
                        <dynamic-dropdown [referringForm]="form" />
                    }
                    @case ("divOpen"){
                        <dynamic-divopen [referringForm]="form" />
                    }
                    @case ("divClose"){
                        <dynamic-divclose [referringForm]="form" />
                    }
                    @default {
                        <dynamic-text-input [referringForm]="form" />
                    }
                }
```